# How to I connnect using window Log on credential in c#.Net

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating C# desktop application in which I want user to perform action only after validating the windows LogOn password for current user.

I want to know how do I check if password is set on windows or not (for current logged in user).

- If Password set then I want to validate the same to proceed .
- If Password not set then no need to validate to proceed.

I have used the following :

```
string UserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, null, null, UserName, Password);

userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, UserName);
```

But the problem is that if there is no password set then I get an error if I passed a blank password.

I am not able to verify if password is not set.

Comment: Why? The application is already running under the user's account. The credentials were already validated when the user logged on or unlocked the computer. `there is no password` that's the whole point

Comment: I want to show some important/confidential information regarding app. so first I want  the users to validate the window password again.

Comment: This is a great way to phish someone's password.

Comment: @DilipKumar you can ask Windows to do this for you, using the OS's UI and credential mechanism, through CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials. Depending on the stack you use (WinForms, WPF, UWP, WinUI) there may be a way to call this directly eg using the [CredentialPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.ui.credentialpicker?view=winrt-22621) class. You'll have to [take care how you display such prompts though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/asking-the-user-for-credentials)

Comment: @DilipKumar there may be other ways to verify the user, similar to how some mobile applications work. For example [UserConsentVerifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.ui.userconsentverifier?view=winrt-22621) will ask for extra consent through a PIN or fingerprint, the way mobile apps do.